# Dynamic value of textarea with Play framework with Silhouette

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, silhouette

There is a need to perform parsing of data from textarea and keep it safe on page update to let it be easily changeable for further experiments.

Before I have added the Silhouette to the app everything was pretty ok.

The page was getting the input parameter:

```
@(textToParse: String)
```

and its value was passed to plain HTML tag like:

```
<textarea ...>@textToParse</textarea>
```

But when I have added the Silhouette and used the form field construtor, I have met a problem:

```
@import b3.inline.fieldConstructor

@b3.textarea(someForm("text"), 'rows -> "12", 'value -> "@textToParse")
```

displays hardcoded "@textToParse" instead of the parameter value.

Skipping the quotes ('value -> @textToParse) leads to compilation error:

```
Type mismatch: found (Nothing) => (Symbol, Nothing), required (Symbol, Any)
```

I have checked the documentation on offsite http://silhouette.mohiva.com/docs/ and googled, but with no result.

Any working suggestions will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code must look like:

```
@b3.textarea(someForm("text"), 'rows -> "12", 'value -> textToParse)
```

With [Twirl](https://github.com/playframework/twirl), the Play template engine, you start an expression with the `@` sign. So in your case you start the expression with the [Bootstrap 3](https://github.com/adrianhurt/play-bootstrap3) form helper. All other which is in the expression must be normal Scala code.

Comment: Seems I was too tired to check so obvious solution :)

Thanks a lot. It worked as it should. 

Kind regards.